# Is it possible to find the tension of a rope from which a plate is hanging from the ceiling?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows a homogeneous triangular shaped plate.
>   Find the tension of the wire which is holding the plate to the
>   ceiling. The mass of the plate is $15\,kg$. The lenght indicated with
>   two paralell lines indicates that the mentioned sides are the same.
>   You may consider that the acceleration due gravity is
>   $10\frac{m}{s^2}$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&50\,N\\
2.&70\,N\\
3.&90\,N\\
4.&100\,N\\
5.&120\,N\\
\end{array}$

I'm confused about this question as no other information is given. How exactly am I supposed to find the tension in the wire as the geometry of the object doesn't really provide much information other than being a triangle. It doesn't say if it is equilateral or anything and there isn't any clue of what sort it can be. I'm assuming that the way to approach this problem would be using the condition of equilibrium as as the sum of torques would be equated to zero. But how to establish the distance to the center of this figure?, can somebody help me with this?.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the solution lies in the torques.

We need to assume that there's no horizontal static frictional force at the point of contact on the floor. Then the only torques are from the gravitational force and from the upward force exerted by the floor. The gravitational force can be supposed to apply to the centre of mass, and the horizontal distance of the centre of mass from the vertical line of suspension is $\frac13$ that of the supported tip. Thus the gravitational force must be $3$ times the upward force at the tip, so $\frac23$ of the gravitational force, or $100N$, are carried as tension by the rope.

Comment: One can also consider the axis of rotation to be the point of contact with the floor. The advantage is that there's then no torque due to the contact force from the floor, so one may directly compare the torque due to tension with the torque due to the plate's weight.

Comment: @Semiclassical: I'm not sure how this is more direct (in either case, there are two torques to consider and the third torque vanishes), but it's certainly a good alternative :-)

Comment: @joriki If you could add a diagram or drawing to your answer I could understand it better to visualize what you meant by identifying the acting forces in the body. How can I prove that the horizontal distance of the center of mass from the suspension is $\frac{1}{3}$ of the tip?. Are you suggesting a barycenter?. I'm not good with geometry. Can you help me with this part please?. How do we come to the conclusion that the gravitational force is 3 times the upward force at the tip?. Can you help me with this part using some equation?.

Comment: Well, it allows us to dispense with assumptions about the direction of the contact force. That said, there's no 'assumption' needed: None of the other forces can act horizontally in that picture, so there can't be any horizontal contact force if the system is to be in equilibrium.

Comment: @Semiclassical: That's true; on the other hand we're both also making the assumption that the rope is vertical. In a problem that spuriously labels two irrelevant lengths as equal, who knows which assumptions are warranted :-)

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: I don't like to draw diagrams :-) I'm not sure what you mean by "are you suggesting a barycenter". As far as I'm aware, "barycentre" is the term used for the centre of mass when two or more bodies are involved, which isn't the case here. That the gravitational force is $3$ times the upward force at the tip follows directly from the ratio of the distances being $\frac13$, since the resulting torque on the plate must be $0$ in equilibrium, so the force with $\frac13$ of the lever must be $3$ times as strong. That leaves your question how we get the factor $\frac13$...

Comment: @joriki The thing with this problem it really would help me to see the justification with a diagram as to looking it from words, makes it harder for me to guess if I'm also understanding what you meant. The thing which is not very clear to me yet is **why** the gravitational force is $3$ times the upward force?. Is it an identity or something which I'm overlooking is there a justification for this?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: ... See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_triangle). Note that the "height" of the triangle in the vertical direction grows linearly in the $x$ direction from the tip to the vertical edge. Thus the average $x$ coordinate, as measured from the tip leftwards, is

$$
\frac{\int_0^L\lambda x\cdot x\mathrm dx}{\int_0^L\lambda x\mathrm dx}=\frac{\frac13L^3}{\frac12L^2}=\frac23L\;,
$$

where $L$ is the horizontal distance from the tip to the vertical edge. Thus, the distance from the centre of mass to the vertical edge is $L-\frac23L=\frac13L$.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: But I just gave you the justification. It's $3$ times the upward force because it balances the torque of the upward force and has $\frac13$ the lever. What more justification do you want? Even if I liked drawing diagrams (which I don't), I wouldn't know where to start to draw a diagram that gives a better justification of that fact than that.

Comment: @joriki That's exactly what I was referring in my earlier comment, if you were referring to the centroid of the triangle. The article which you had mentioned links to that. I think that a more intuitive answer would had been to say... recall the centroid of a triangle?. Because the triangular plate is supported at one tip is difficult to spot where exactly the center of mass is considering the intersection of medians. This is why I suggested the inclusion of a drawing perhaps superimposed to mine. I got the idea of the length. But if you show it explicitly is easier to get the idea.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: I have no way of knowing which terms are more familiar to you than others. To me, "centre of mass" is more familiar, and I had to look up "centroid" the first time I saw it on this site. If I understand correctly it's the other way around for you. That doesn't mean that one or the other is more intuitive.

Comment: @joriki There's also why exactly, was it really needed to know that the length of the wire to be the same as the vertical side of the triangle?. If those had been different would had been also $\frac{L}{3}$?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: As I mentioned in passing above, this information is irrelevant; it was probably just put there to distract you. The plate could be suspended from the moon as far as we're concerned.

Comment: @joriki So the torque condition is established a horizontal distance from the force to that the center of mass?. Is this the definition?. I believe that for this whole situation to work you had to assume that the plate is put at a vertical to the ceiling otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: Yes, I mentioned that above; we need to assume that the rope and the edge beneath it are vertical. The problem is rather badly posed, with irrelevant length information and without making explicit assumptions. We need to make one of two assumptions: Either that there's no horizontal static frictional force at the tip, or that the rope is vertical – each implies the other (since there can't be just one horizontal force acting in equilibrium).